# .htaccess - lose the file .html extension

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a bad .htaccess day!

I want a user to be able to type the URL

> mysite.com/about

instead of

> mysite.com/about.html

On .htaccess file I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1.html [NC,L]
```

But this simply does not work?

I will add though that if i try this further inside the site e.g.

```
mysite.com/pages/contact
```

Works perfectly whether I have the above code in the .htaccess or not

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not a direct solution, but moving the file to about/index.html gives you the same result.

Comment: There should be NO leading slash when matching in RewriteRule if placed in .htaccess. Try this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [NC,L]`

Comment: Also, instead of using mod_rewrite, you can look at `Options` directive, `MultiViews` in particular: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just avoid slashes before both matching patterns and destination.
So,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

should work perfectly.